# Best practice in storing data to be used on multiple devices?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, sharepoint, microsoft-teams

I'm currently making Microsoft Teams custom Tabs that utilize Sharepoint to store information. And, there could be multiple instances of that Tabs , each with its own Sharepoint file. 
What is the best way to link or connect the  Tabs to its corresponding Sharepoint File? Is there a way to store information on Microsoft Teams Tabs that persist through different device?
At the moment I store Tabs' entityId obtained from MS Teams SDK context on the Sharepoint Files related to that Tabs. Then on the custom tab, I queried the sharepoint site for the file that has a matching entityId with the tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As part of adding the tab to the Team, there is a "configuration" page, where you set the final url for the specific instance of that tab. Part of that configuration could be setting a custom querystring variable that will get passed to the tab, telling it which file to access. For instance, the final tab url could be:

https://my.domain.com/mytab.html?spfile=abc.docx

and another tab with:

https://my.domain.com/mytab.html?spfile=def.docx

That's exactly what the "configuration" page is for when you set up a tab, I think -scenarios like this.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the use of querystring, but this should work. In my case, I think I can store the Sharepoint list's ID on the URL to do a GET operation later.
Thanks for the asnwer.